# What are quant trading competitions besides IQC?

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, quants

I am interested to participate quantitative trading competitions. I am residing in Singapore.

The only quant trading competitions that I know are International Quant Championship ([IQC](https://www.worldquantvrc.com/en/cms/wqc/iqc/)) and [SMU Alphathon](https://www.worldquantvrc.com/en/cms/wqc/smu-alphathon/).

Are there anymore quant trading competitions either in Singapore or online?

Answer (score 1):

XTX are running a competition for a stock prediction model https://challenge.xtxmarkets.com

There is also a technical assessment as a precursor.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Algo Challenge Association (https://algochallenge.org/).
They organize global algo-trading competitions every year. Each time the theme will have different underlying market (eg. FX, Equity, Crypto, etc).

The quant platform (https://algogene.com) used in their contests is really sophisticated and powerful.